# PhpStorm option to not insert a line break after an in-line comment

Tags: phpstorm, code-formatting, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to adjust the code formatter in PhpStorm and I can't find what rule is causing a certain re-formatting to happen.  In general, if there's some way to know which rules/settings caused a certain change to happen, that would be great for debugging my setup.

The specific issue I'm trying to address is that the formatter is forcing a line break after an in-line comment.

For example, the following code:

```
array_search($needle, $haystack, /*strict=*/true);
```

Is being turned into:

```
array_search($needle, $haystack, /*strict=*/
             true);
```

And I can't find the setting that controls this.  Anyone know which setting controls this, or more generally, how to see a log of which rules are being applied so I can debug behaviors like this?

(I'm running PhpStorm 2018.3.5)

Comment: This relevant? : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119435#comment=27-1834754, sry if not

Comment: There is no corresponding setting in PhpStorm. This wrong behavior has been fixed in PhpStorm 2019.1 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32166), please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Olga Strizhenko commented, I've confirmed this issue is fixed in version 2019.1.